# How to make the only content of a list item a list?

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I create a list which looks like this in Word?

```
1. Foo
2. Bar
3. For example:
   a.  1. Foo
       2. Bar
       3. Baz
   b.  1. Foo
       2. Bar
       3. Baz
4. Baz
```

In terms of HTML, this would require this markup:

```
<ol>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li>
        For example:
        <ol>
            <li>
                <ol>
                    <li>Foo</li>
                    <li>Bar</li>
                    <li>Baz</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li>
                <ol>
                    <li>Foo</li>
                    <li>Bar</li>
                    <li>Baz</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
       </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Baz</li>
</ol>
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to make Word create this "empty" second level list. I'm using Word 2011 (Mac OS X).

Comment: Lists, like tables, get really buggy in Word when you go this far. I suppose that there's a reason you're doing this in Word and not HTML?

Comment: I'm translating a Japanese text and mistakenly assumed it would be helpful to first write the whole thing out in Word in its original form (transferring from paper). Apparently that's not the case. ;o) I have already moved over to HTML, since that'll be the final form anyway, but I'm still interested how to do this in Word.

Comment: You should be able to do it with VBA in Word, or any decent scripting language outside of Word.

Comment: @Joe OK, this just made me decide not to touch Word again for anything more than a letter to my mother. I thought WYSIWYG was supposed to be *easier*... ;oP

Comment: @deceze  since you're holding space or using tab anyway, to make  the HTML code look pretty/readable, why not just hold space or use tab, doing it manually in MS Word?

Comment: @barlop HTML is auto-indented by any decent HTML editor. I *don't* need to hold space to achieve this. Furthermore, if my lines are longer than the page is wide, they'll wrap and I have to fight with manually indenting the wrapped lines. That's not what I'm using an expensive full-fledged WYSIWYG word processor for that's supposed to handle exactly these things.

Comment: @deceze Like most things meant to be easy, they make easy things easier and hard things harder.

Answer (score 0):

turn off automatic bulleting and do it manually.  i don't use automatic bulleting ever. it's a second or two to tap  a. or 3.  and push spaces a few times and possibly hold space for a moment

Comment: So basically, "Word is stupid and it doesn't work"? :)

Comment: @deceze I like MS Word and use it for a lot of things, it does a lot of things very well, but  I always found the automatic bullet feature(when it was added), a pain in the ass, something to turn off or not use.  If somebody ever told me they found it useful.. i'd give it another look.   I turn off the "startup task pane"('cos I only open documents anyway normally), and certainly I turn off the "canvas"(that was a silly addition they did), and of course clippy..   I've put word to good use for writing documents, with tables, drawings, making unimportant things size 8 or less..

Comment: @deceze i've only found it a nightmare when it autosaves a document opened over a network, and the cable isn't in.. or the cable is damaged and it can't save.. and I can lose stuff. Then it's horrendous. But other than that , it works great for all I need it for, and it's very reliable. Some features are BS.. I would suspect, that the automatic bullets feature is BS.i.e. It's never been useful to me, and I suspect that if I did fiddle with it and figure out its 'power' I wouldn't find much power and I might still find it too fiddly.

Comment: @deceze prob not as bad as clippy, but like clippy in that I didn't have to mess with it much or at all to realise or suspect i should turn it off. But I also had the benefit of using Word -before- it so I never treated it as normal! Of course, if somebody came along that  used automatic bullets a lot and likes them  and spoke/wrote that'd be great. if it happens..they may be right, but until then i'm not so inclined to bother fiddling with them in the low chance hope that they turn out to be great.

Comment: Looking at MS Word 2k3 on XP, a)you can't do multiple layered lists in an automated way b)you can only do numbered lists or bullet lists automatically, not automatically a lettered list like a,b,c.  So your example can't be done..for those two reasons.  No disaster since no need to use automatic list anyway.

Comment: You *really* like Word, don't you? :o) Sorry to say that I *always* seem to find the 5% that are not working whenever I touch it and hence have little respect for it. I'm possibly too old-school for WYSIWYG.

Comment: @deceze I'm open to conversion. The network issue I mentioned drove me mad.I would use a text editor except I like flexible font size changes mainly and being able to insert images helps. But using html to format documents, having to open up a browser to view any document.either links/lynx(from a command prompt) not convenient,or a GUI browser(a pain, can't edit easily).I suppose if you want to read your documents you start up your HTML editor?which is that? still not ideal'cos if putting pics in the document they need to be separate files which is a bit messy.neater to be able to embed them.

Comment: I have come to really prefer a structured markup language such as Markdown, Restructured Text or, why not, HTML. For really heavy-duty document generation nothing beats LaTeX I suppose, but I haven't had the chance to use it much yet. Separating the *logical structure* (markup) from the *visual styling* (CSS, LaTeX rules) is incredibly powerful and allows you much more control. Trying to get both things done at once in a WYSIWYG editor always feels like a tightrope walk where I'm constantly fighting to stay upright. Anyway, didn't mean to turn this into a pro/anti Word discussion.

Comment: @deceze:  Coincidentally, Wordperfect was heavy in the markup department. It sucked **a big hairy toe** for new users. Great for veteran WP users. It just another case of pick the right tool for the job.

Comment: @deceze yeah nobody's doubting that you get control, but you need a good method of viewing or editing them. And if you have many images it's just not as neat in terms of files since it needs multiple ones. even a directory of images. And ditto, if you're talking CSS using separate files. Just for one document. Suppose you want to copy the document somewhere, not so easy.